# How to use List or IList in place of IEnumerable in Asp.NET MVC Views name spaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My understanding about IList is it implements both IEnumerable and ICollection.
and List is a concrete implementation of IList interface.

So I had used IEnumerable in the view namespaces many times to iterate over model objects.
But when using IList or List in the namespaces, I'm getting an

> **Server Error in '/' Application**

So,

1. Why is this happening? and
2. If I want to use List or IList what should be done?

Action in Controller :

```
private DummyProjectContext db = new DummyProjectContext();
  // GET: BankAccounts
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<BankAccount> ba = db.BankAccounts.ToList();
        return View(ba);
    }
```

Index.cshtml :

```
@model IList<DummyProject.Models.BankAccount>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Well, I know there IEnumerable is sufficient for this example and that should be used. I want to know why using IList or List , I'm getting this error?

Comment: You need to add a using statement `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Well I've used this namespace in my controller and tried in view also ,something like that :[ @using System.Collections.Generic ]. But this didn't worked. Could you Kindly elaborate what are you saying

Comment: @Subhadeep: Not seems it's related to the using `IList`. Check one more time: replace  by `IList` by `IEnumerable` and run again.

Comment: @Jackdaw I've mentioned in the question that, using IEnumerable I'm getting the desired result. My question was why we can't use List or IList here ? OR what is the scenario where List should be used ?

Comment: @Subhadeep: Show all error description (should be yellow page), please. The `Server Error in '/' Application.` is only title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get an error here. Use Inumerable will resolve this error.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
...

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I Created Asp.net Project And Added a Dummy List But I Have not gotten that error Maybe Your list Object Is Null.

Controller:

```
var s=new List<string>();
s.add("test");
return view(s);

view:
@model IList<string>

<ul>
  @foreach(var item in Model)
  {
   <li>item</li>
  }
</ul>
```

For More trouble shooting:
Please copy all the stack trace of an error when You run project for seeing complete error. It maybe occurred for other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the question contains two errors and doesn't compiling:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
...

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
...
```

You have to fix these errors.

***UPDATE:***

*Just for test, try to replace two lines above by:*

`@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.FirstOrDefault().Name)`

*and*

`@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.FirstOrDefault().Amount)`

*Use* `@model IList<DummyProject.Models.BankAccount>` *and let me know if will be any changes.*

Comment: Yes you are correct. Using IEnumerable<DummyProject.Models.BankAccount> as a namespace, this code works perfectly. My question is using model IList<DummyProject.Models.BankAccount>in namspace why this line is doen't contain implementation for these 2 lines ? Keeping this in mind: IList implements both IEnumerable and ICollection[source: csharpcorner]